# Mocking Play WSRequestHolder get method using Scalamock

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, scalatest, scalamock

I'm trying to test the following line of code using ScalaTest and ScalaMock.

```
val responseFuture = wsClient.url(url).withQueryString(params: _*).get()
```

`wsClient` type is `THttpClient`, which is a wrapper of `play.api.libs.ws.WS`.

Given that:

```
val mockHttpClient = mock[THttpClient]
```

is properly injected into my class under test, the test code is something like this:

```
val expectedUrl = "some url"
val mockRequestHolder = mock[WSRequestHolder]
inSequence {
  (mockHttpClient.url _).expects(expectedUrl).returns(mockRequestHolder)
  (mockRequestHolder.withQueryString _).expects(where {
    (parameters: Seq[(String, String)]) => {
      // assertions on parameters
      // ...
      true
    }
  }).returns(mockRequestHolder)

  val stubResponse = stub[WSResponse]
  val jsonBody = "{}"
  (stubResponse.json _).when().returns(Json.parse(jsonBody))
  (mockRequestHolder.get _).expects().returns(Future(stubResponse))
}
```

IntelliJ is highlighting `mockRequestHolder.get` as an error saying: cannot resolve symbol get. Nevertheless I'm able to run the test but the mock is clearly not working, and I'm getting: java.util.NoSuchElementException: JsError.get.

The mock is working when I try to mock any other method of `WSRequestHolder`, but not with method `get`.

Is this a ScalaMock bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have solved already the issue, but I have tried to do something similar recently and I kind of got it working with the following code:

```
val wsClientMock = mock[WSClient]
val wsRequestMock = mock[WSRequest]
val wsResponseMock = mock[WSResponse]
(wsRequestMock.withAuth _).expects(username, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC).returning(wsRequestMock)
(wsRequestMock.get _).expects().returning(Future[WSResponse](wsResponseMock))
(wsClientMock.url _).expects(bootstrapUrl).returning(wsRequestMock)
(wsResponseMock.status _).expects().returning(200)
```

"kind of" because I need to mock also the response, otherwise I get results like

```
ERROR[default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] OneForOneStrategy - Unexpected call: json()
```

due to the fact that the code calling the WSClient is calling the method .json of WSResponse.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know Scala Mock but I suggest you to have a look at MockWS a library which comes with a mocked WS client: [play-mockws](https://github.com/leanovate/play-mockws)

With MockWS you define a partial function which returns an Action for a Route. This enables you to precisely configure mocked answers and test your http client code.